# Replace String in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am a beginner in jquery. I want to ask how to replace the following string:

```
<SequenceNumber>33214</SequenceNumber>
<TransactionCode>71</TransactionCode>
<TransactionAmount>100000</TransactionAmount>
<LedgerBalance>14722600.2</LedgerBalance>
```

be like this:

```
Sequence Number = 33214
Transaction Code = 71
Transaction Amount = 100000
Ledger Balance = 14722600.2
```

so each string with the following format

```
<Tag>Value</Tag>
```

would be like this:

```
Tag = Value
```

please help, thanks

Comment: Is the input part of an XML file?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RegEx [`<([^>]+)>([^<]+)<\/\1>`](https://regex101.com/r/2EqWrn/1)

And replace with `$1 = $2`

- `<([^>]+)>` matches anything inside the first `<>`
- `([^<]+)` matches anything but a `<` 1 or more times
- `<\/\1>` makes sure the closing tag is the same as the opening one

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/2EqWrn/1)

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below will do exactly what you need.

```js
var content = $('#content');
var dom = $.parseHTML(content.html());
var result = ""
$.each(dom, function (index, element) {
  switch(element.nodeType) {
    case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
      result += element.localName;
      result += " = ";
      result += element.textContent;
      result += "<br/>";
      break;
  }
});
content.html(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <tag1>value</tag1>
  <tag2>value2</tag2>
  <tag3>value3</tag3>
</div>
```